# create-react-app : useEffect hook dependencies warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I always use the react code base from [npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/).

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const _someFunction = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(actionB(dataB))
    } catch (error) {
      // 
    }

  }, [dispatch]); <- here 2

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('text : ', text);
    dispatch(actionA(dataA));
    _someFunction();
  }, [text, dispatch, _someFunction]); <- here 1

  return (
    <div className="App">
        hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

At 'here 1', I can understand 'text' has to be present in the [] of useEffect, since it is the changing factor to trigger useEffect.

For 'dispatch', it is not the changing factor, so I believe it is not required to be placed inside the []. This is also the same for '_someFunction'.

However, if I do not place 'dispatch' and '_someFunction', the console will warn me something like this:-

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Also, I know using `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` inside useEffect can suppress the warning.

I wish to know the proper way. My question is:-

1. is it necessary to include all 'text', 'dispatch', '_someFunction' in the [], so that I can obey the create-create-app based console warning, or
2. I shall only include the factors to be detected, that is 'text' to trigger useEffect. in order to suppress warning for successful CD / CI, I may apply `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to exclude other unwanted dependencies e.g. 'dispatch', '_someFunction'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Don't suppress warning

If warnings are there there is a reason! If the needed stuff makes it impossible to achieve what you need, you are just using a wrong pattern!

### You don't always need hooks

why don't you just have another function in between avoiding the useEffect?

```
const onChange=(value)=>{
  setText(value);
  dispatch(actionA(dataA));
  _someFunction();
}
```

useEffect is used to update the whole component whenever it has to.

### But i want to use hooks!

Fine, you can do that! The important is that you don't use a normal function as first argument, use a hook instead.
What you've done would be:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("text : ", text);
}, [text]);

const dispatchCallback = useCallback(() => {
  dispatch(actionA(dataA));
}, [actionA, dataA]);

useEffect(dispatchCallback, [text]);

useEffect(_someFunction, [text]);
```

See? each effect is independent. You are calling the callbacks whenever the variable text changes.

**I would not recommend this pattern!** Too many hooks and is not very useful!

Comment: If warnings are there there is a reason -> I strongly agree on that. Especially it is provided by create react app.